# SQL query not using index

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing

I am trying to execute one sql query that fetches data from table using an **IN** query in **WHERE** clause.

when result-set is small, it is woking properly but when resultset is high.
It is not using indexes properly.
Table schema is like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
  `xyz_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL, //not unique
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `emp_id_user_id_idx` (`emp_id`,`xyz_id`));
```

Query is like

```
select * from users where xyz_id = "123" and emp_id in (123, 124, 234, 134);
```

Am I mising something, as it takes too much time when result set is high.

Explain query result.

```
          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: users
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: emp_id_user_id_idx,
          key: emp_id_user_id_idx
      key_len: 1032
          ref: NULL
         rows: 8366888
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition
```

Comment: Please firstly, do not use double quotes (") for comparing string.. use (').. and.. what is your problem? can you provide expected result?

Comment: @PeterKsenak: Noted to use ('). expected result is same but time taken is too much for high resultset

Comment: what you mean "not using indices properly"?

Comment: I mean query is taking much more time. explain is showing possible keys fine but result time is much high

Comment: Please add the explain plan and what engine is the table using(innodb?)

Comment: you can run `show index` command and verify indexing sequence is maintained properly in your `where`  clause which may help in your debugging.

Comment: @user404: can you provide an example. It will be very helpful

Comment: @Geek_To_Learn, please check my answer below.

Comment: @user404: Thanks for help But I have tried same way. Nothing changed :(

Comment: How many records is the result ? `select COUNT(*) from users where xyz_id = "123" and emp_id in (123, 124, 234, 134);` ..  What i see from the explain is that the query is using the range index scan/seek and MySQL optimizer expects it needs to search in 8366888 records to get the results..

Comment: What you can try because in MySQL the `IN()` is a simple `OR`  concat filter which tends to optimize bad is the following.. `select * from users where xyz_id = '123' and emp_id = 123 UNION select * from users where xyz_id = '123' and emp_id = 124  ...` which tends to optimize better. Oracle database does this optimizing method also i hope MySQL get this feature as well as MySQL is owned by Oracle Corp.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command

```
show index from users;
```

you will get a a column named: `Seq_in_index`
In your `where` clause you must maintain that order/sequence for the columns name you have used for condition. Like, from your query:

```
select * from users where xyz_id = "123" and emp_id in (123, 124, 234, 134);
```

Here `xyz_id` column should have less value in `Seq_in_index` than `emp_id` column, Otherwise, indexing won't work here. Simply, you have to maintain the order.

Please, let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks for help But I have tried same way. Nothing changed :(

Comment: A lower `Seq_in_index` means that the column was earlier in the `INDEX` definition.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
select *
from users
where xyz_id = 123 and emp_id in (123, 124, 234, 134);
```

The optimal index is on `users(xyz_id, emp_id)`.  Your index has the keys in the other order.

So, only the first key of your index can be used (by MySQL) for this query.  Some databases support an enhanced index access mechanism called skip-scans, which would allow your index to be used.  MySQL does not.

How is the proper index used?  MySQL can immediately go to the values for `xyz_id`, because there is an equality comparison.  It can then pick out the values of `emp_id`.

Also, be careful about the types that you use.  If an id is a number, do not compare the value to a string.  Also this happens to work, there is an implicit conversion (in this case on the constant value) and conversions can preclude the use of an index.

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Newer versions have something that might be equivalent to "skip-scan", called MRR(?).  Still, flipping the key would be better.  Maybe MRR can handle one direction but not the other.

Comment: @RickJames . . . I am not aware that MRR implements any new functionality -- that is, cases when the index would be used.  It might make the OPs version of the query more efficient.